# No Module named "sklearn"

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am trying to import 'sklearn' using Python 3.4.3 on a Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspian.
I downloaded microconda3, which includes all the necessary modules to use scikit.
However, when I attempt to import 'sklearn' in IDLE, I receive an error stating that there is no module named 'sklearn'.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct Python?

Comment: I can't say with 100% certainty that I am. For what it's worth, the current version of IDLE is 3.4.2. I am fairly certain Python 3.4.3 came with the miniconda3 installation.

Comment: miniconda doesn't contain any of the libraries that Anaconda does. Only Python + Conda

Comment: it showed various modules such as scikit and numpy when I was doing the install. Are those not installed as well?

Comment: Maybe you actually installed Anaconda, then

Comment: I definitely did not install anaconda it had miniconda3 all over it.

Comment: I suspect the IDLE you are opening is not the one linked to your miniconda interpreter. How are you opening IDLE? What is the output of `which python`?

Comment: which python returns " /home/pi/miniconda3/bin/python ". I open python 3 either by clicking a shortcut on my desktop or by opening a python 3 file I started the same way. EDIT: using a conda install on scipy shows that I already have it installed as well as scikit-learn

Comment: Also, if you have `conda` you should use `conda` to install libraries part of the `scipy` stack

Comment: I am pretty sure that the IDLE version that is being opened automatically when you click on an icon is not the one linked to the right interpreter. I'm not sure exactly how to change that on Raspian, but it's probably easy enough to Google. Or maybe get a text editor and use the terminal? IDLE is pretty bare-bones anyway...

Comment: that seems like a likely issue. I've only ever used IDLE but I am not opposed to trying something new.

Comment: Take a look at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46045916/8290688)

Answer (score 1):

You can install the module with the following command using pip:
 `pip install -U scikit-learn`.

See: [Scikit-learn Docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html/%20Scikit-learn%20Docs)

Comment: I had attempted that before but tried again. It returns an error stating that I need SciPy to install scikit-learn, but the attempted SciPy has a compile failure with error code 1 in "/tmp/pip-build-pb0w9u9_/scipy"

Comment: Try upgrading pip with: pip install --upgrade pip. Then try again.

Comment: pip was out of date. when I attempted the scipy install again, it threw a similar error. earlier on in the process, it failed to build the wheel for scipy

Comment: There seems to be widespread problems installing scipy using pip on windows. From other  SO answers, there appear to be 2 solutions: install anaconda and then run the command `conda install scipy` or download the windows binary from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy). Apologies I can't offer any more assistance, have a look at some similar questions on SO. Your best bet sounds like going down the anaconda route.

Comment: You've defitnitely helped narrow it down. Oddly enough, when I installed miniconda3, it installs SciPy and scikit-learn, so when I attempt to do a conda install of SciPy it says I already have it installed. There must be some issue with IDLE's ability to talk to the module.

Comment: Glad I could help. Atleast you got there in the end!

Answer (score 1):

Try starting fresh and reinstall all of the necessary modules through miniconda3. Maybe the scikit-learn included on that install did not work.

You can then try

`sudo apt-get install python3-scipy python3-sklearn`

Comment: maybe this is how it works, but I already said this in my edit that you deleted.

Comment: @csoltis You are supposed to actually answer the question (down here) rather than edit the question ;)